# From / By a different method

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

I need to send an email to my manager saying I got some details from an insurance using a different method other than calling them.

But I wasn't sure which is correct from below sentences.

1. I managed to contact the insurance from a different method.
2. I managed to contact the insurance by a different method.

I know there are several threads under this topic in this site. But still I could not figure out which is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The first is not correct. The second one works, but I might suggest "by different means" or "by other means" in this context instead.

(A *means* is a way of doing something that has a bit more breadth to my ears than a *method* which implies something a little more precise or technical.)

Also: "an insurance" is not grammatical here. You want to say "the insur**er**", or "the insurance company" or "the insurance provider" or "our insurance agent", etc, as appropriate-- "insurance" refers to the intangible product/contract that you have, not to the entity which provides it.

Comment: You are correct. I tried to say "an insurance company". Thank you for that. But could you please explain the difference between from and by usage here?

Comment: I'm not sure what else there is to explain. :) You can contact someone *from a place* ("I contacted them from Guatemala!") but just as you can't contact someone "from the email" or "from their website contact form" you can't contact them "from a method".